# Filtering and array mapping issue in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, rxjs

This is a translate of the original question, sorry for the english

I'm creating a filter for the notifications of an app I'm working on, the app is in react, the thing is this, I'm trying to use filter and map, but for some reason, I think it's probably some syntax error on my part, it does not do the filtering part, in the data I receive there is a value called status, if this is completed I want it to be removed from the new array.

status is located in notifications.data.status I put below the way I receive the data

[notifications.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF3I9.png)

It only does the mapping, I have to use Object.keys, because of the rest it gives me a compiled error, thank you very much

```
          <GlobalNotifications id="GlobalNotifications">
            {/* {console.log(Object.keys(notifications.data).filter(notification => notification.status !== 'completed'))} */}
            {console.log(Object.values(notifications.data))}
            {Object.keys(notifications.data)
              .filter(notification => notification.status !== 'completed')
              .map(key => (
                <NotificationItem
                  id={key}
                  key={key}
                  data={notifications.data[key]}
                  openHistory={openHistory === key}
                  callbackOpenHistory={onOpenHistory}
                />
              ))}
          </GlobalNotifications>
```

Comment: Questions must be in English. Please translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notifications.data is already an array, so you don't need to use Object.keys() to return an array.

```
filteredArray = data
  .filter((notification) => notification.status === "accepted")
```

Then map the returned filtered array (I used 'accepted' as it gave more elements to play with) based on each item.
.map((item) => { the brackets for your code and return(make sure to return your jsx within these parentheses)})

It is best to use a unique key when making a list, so I chose to use your item._id for the key. Sample Data and code below followed by output

```
    import "./styles.css";
    let data = [
      {
        status: "completed",
        events: [],
        _id: 1
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 2
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 3
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 4
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 5
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 6
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 7
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 8
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 9
      },
      {
        status: "accepted",
        events: [],
        _id: 10
      }
    ];
    const filteredArray = data
      .filter((notification) => notification.status === "accepted")
      .map((item) => {
        let key = item._id;
        return (
          <div key={key}>
            id: {key}; status: {item.status}
          </div>
        );
      });
```

Output:

id: 2; status: accepted

id: 3; status: accepted

id: 4; status: accepted

id: 5; status: accepted

id: 6; status: accepted

id: 7; status: accepted

id: 8; status: accepted

id: 9; status: accepted

id: 10; status: accepted

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove the rxjs tag as your question is related to JavaScript higher order functions on arrays but has nothing to do with rxjs